# How to order SQL results in Full Text Searches

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use full text search in my project. When I use Natural Language Full-Text Searches
with more than word, it works fine for me. Here are some examples of my code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('some exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

I can also do this to get score and order it by score:

```
SELECT *,
    MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('some exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as scor 
    FROM table 
    WHERE MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('some exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

The problem is when I use one word for my search like this:

```
SELECT *,
    MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as scor 
    FROM table 
    WHERE MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

It gives me more results with same scores sorted in ascending. For me, I want to order it by `id DESC`, but I can't do that.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, what are you *actually* using? What does PHP have to do with your question?

Comment: i am using PHP 8.1 for know, my problem is how to order the results by id DESC when i have the same score

Comment: Have you tried appending `ORDER BY id DESC` at the veryend of your query?

Comment: *"i am using PHP 8.1 "* That doesn't tell us what PHP has to do with the problem or what RDBMS you are using..

Comment: yes it works, but do this will ordering all columns and will ignore score, for me i want to order by id descending only if has the same score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to order the results by `scor` and `id` in the case of ties. Untested code that will hopefully solve this for you:

```
SELECT *,
    MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as scor 
    FROM table 
    WHERE MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
ORDER score DESC, id
```

Comment: the solution is simple, i have just have to add `ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC` ,  like this : `SELECT *,
    MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as score
    FROM table 
    WHERE MATCH (title, title_ar, title_en) AGAINST ('exemple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)  ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC;` , thank you for everyone help.